# Google Services Framework keeps stopping

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-10.0, lg

I am trying to install Android 10 on an LG Nexus 5x (bullhead) smartphone. I installed the TWRP app, downloaded the Pixel Experience (the OS). I booted into TWRP recovery mode, and installed the OS, then rebooted.

After rebooting, the phone starts with the screen of language setup. Right there, the message "Google Services Framew...keeps stopping" keeps popping up, and I can't press on anything else.

I restarted the phone, went back to TWRP recovery mode, wiped data and installed the OS again. But that message still insists. Is there any way to fix it, or I've just broken the phone forever?

I finally found the offical forum for this Android 10 OS: https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/development/pixelexperience-nexus-5x-t3861437/page141

Apparently, many people also experience this issue. I will look further for the solution on the official forum.

Comment: Is your Nexus 5X worked on Pie? In my case I just updated to Oreo, My phone didn't even booted completely :(. That's all, I changed my mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer. The Pixel Experience ROM must be installed in a decrypted data partition. Mine is encrypted, so I must remove the encryption.

The simple way is, instead of "Wipe", to choose "Format Data" in the TWRP recovery mode, then proceed as usual.